# Velocity replacement of property of items in a list not working

Tags: java, velocity

I have this code:

```
UserRssArticleDTO rssArticleDTO = new UserRssArticleDTO();
rssArticleDTO.title = "Calves won in NBA";
ArrayList<UserRssArticleDTO> dtoList = new ArrayList<UserRssArticleDTO>();
dtoList.add(rssArticleDTO);

VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();

ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("peasant","farmer"));
context.put("rssArticleDTOList", dtoList);
context.put("date", new Date());
context.put("time", new Date());

StringWriter swOut = new StringWriter();
String templateStr = buffer.toString();

/**
* Merge data and template
*/
Velocity.evaluate( context, swOut, "log tag name", templateStr);
System.out.println(swOut);
```

The `UserRssArticleDTO`:

```
class UserRssArticleDTO {
    public String title;
    public String desctiption;
    public String dummy;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getDesctiption() {
        return desctiption;
    }
    public void setDesctiption(String desctiption) {
        this.desctiption = desctiption;
    }
    public String getDummy() {
        return dummy;
    }
    public void setDummy(String dummy) {
        this.dummy = dummy;
    }
}
```

The velocity template:

```
#foreach( $rssArticleDTO in $rssArticleDTOList )
    <div>
        <div>$date </div>
        <div>$rssArticleDTO.title</div>
        <div>$time</div>
    </div>
#end
```

The output is `$rssArticleDTO.title` instead of showing the value of the title.

If I use the a string list instead or `rssArticleDTOList`, then there is no issue in printing value.

If I use `$rssArticleDTO`, then the `toString` method ie the hashcode is being printed.

So please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Please show the code how are you retrieving the value of `rssArticleDTOList` in your velocity template.

Comment: That is being got from a file which I feel irrelevant for our purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the source of the problem. The class UserRssArticleDTO was in the same class as the template. I moved it to its own java file and everything started working.